# PHP form data access and staying on page

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to PHP and HTML as I have programmed more with C++ and C entirely.

I have a webform with a list of scheduled dates for people to choose the date and time from. It's a radio box. The people get to choose from a list of schedules in a week. So there are about 50 time slots to choose from over five days.

The code is something like this (in a file, say generateslots.php):

```
<form name = "input" action = "execute_databaseupdate.php" method = "post">

<?php

    <tr>
     <td><?php echo $today ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $weekday ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $slottime.'-'.$endtime; ?></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
                                <td><?php echo $SumId; ?></td>
    </tr>
    ?>


<input type="submit" name = "submit" id = "sub" value="Submit" >
```

Upon submission I want to make sure that at least a certain number of slots have been selected. If a certain number of schedules have not been chosen then alert the user and then stay on page.

For that I need to have access to all the chosen slots. I can access all the posted data in the execute_databaseupdate.php file and that I do using the $_POST super-global using something like:

```
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check){
    echo $check;
}
```

How can I access the data in the same file generateslots.php, and if the condition is met, allow the execution. Otherwise, pop up the warning message and then *stay* on the *same* page.

I have tried the following:

```
<form name = "input" action = "execute_databaseupdate.php" method = "post" onSubmit = "return CheckData();">
```

In the checkData function, I accessed the data as above, but the superglobal post is empty. I want to access the elements checked upon submission, and I believe that I have to work with check_list array.

```
empty($_POST['check_list'])
```

returns true. I guess I am not able to figure out, after clicking on submit, how to access the submitted data in the generateslots.php file itself and warn the user and further keep the options he/she checked to be active.

Comment: I think you might need to look into Javascript to validate user input and then redirect the user depending on the results.

Comment: Sorry @ybce. I saw your reply just now. Am also getting used to Stack Exchange so I overlooked. Appreciate your reply and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the `POST` data in `generateslots.php`, the form would need to POST *to* `generateslots.php`:

```
<form name = "input" action = "generateslots.php" method = "post">
```

The code for handling that form submission would be moved to that page, generally wrapped in something similar to what you have:

```
if (isset($_POST['check_list'])) {
    // process the form post 
}
// show the form
```

When "processing the form post", if everything is successful, you can redirect the user to another page and essentially cancel the rest of the code on this page.

When "showing the form", you can pre-select form elements and whatnot based on the data in the `POST` if that data is present.

---

I'm mostly guessing as to the nature of what you're currently doing, since the question is a bit light on the necessary details.  (For example, what `CheckData()` is.)  But this sounds like a very common problem faced by new web developers.  Especially those coming from non-web backgrounds.

But basically, what you're *currently* doing sounds like you're trying to access the `POST` data on `generateslots.php` *when the page is first being rendered*, which is *before* anything is ever posted.  An order of operations like this:

- User requests `generateslots.php`
- Server looks for form `POST` data, finds none
- Server returns form
- User submits form to `execute_databaseupdate.php`

Instead, you might do something like this:

- User requests `generateslots.php`
- Server sees no form is posted, shows new empty form
- User submits form to `generateslots.php`
- Server sees a form is posted, processes form
- If successful, server returns a redirect to the next page
- Else, server returns form (with known data so far)

There are, of course, other ways to do it.  It often comes down to a balance between code maintenance, API purity, and personal preference.  These are all things you can discover in time as the needs arise.  But the bottom line is that you process the form submission on the page to which it is submitted.

Comment: Many thanks @David. That was spoton. That is exactly what I am trying to do. The CheckData was supposed to be another trial attempt where I loop through the _POST data and return either true or false based on the desired condition. I did not want to change too much of the code as this has been inherited and I am only doing some addons. But I guess I wll have to change the structure a bit. I will try to first submit it to the same page and then redirect as you suggested. Thanks again

Comment: I did manage to redirect the form. However I still have small issue. I first tried posting to the same page as you suggested using htmlspecialcharacters and PHP_SELF and it worked as in I could loop over the post data and based on the number of selected slots, decide on the next action i.e. redirect and update database. But what I also want to do in case the user selects less than desired number of slots is to 1.) prompt an alert message and in addition, when the user closes the alert box, show the form with the few options the user already selected? Thanks